# Samsung Galaxy Tab 4/Android Studio - Layout not appearing properly on device

Tags: android

Context: I am using Android Studio in Linux, and am trying to develop an app for a Samsung Galaxy Tab 4. According to the "Device in Editor" toolbar option, there is no such device. The code runs from the physical device, but the layout doesn't match what's in the drag-and-drop editor. The buttons aren't even aligned, and text is cut off on the left side.

Since I need the app for this particular Tab, I don't really need an emulator. I've seen similar posts about using drivers, but those are all in Windows.

Question: What measures should I take to get the display showing what I need? Is it a trial/error process, or do I need to install something?

I'm pretty new to both Android Studio and Linux, so I'd appreciate any input but the simpler, the better? Thank you in advance, everyone! :)

Comment: Check this out https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html

Comment: Are you asking about a code issue with your layout or how to create an android virtual device that matches a Samsung Galaxy Tab 4?

Comment: More so the latter than the former. I'm wondering if the issue with my layout can be resolved by having another virtual device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[FIXED] There was an unrelated detail to the above information; I didn't set the constraints/margins. For any new user to Android Studio, you can set [constraints](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html) such that widgets on-screen (like a button, for instance) appear in a certain spot relative to the edge of the screen and to other widgets. Having hard-coded dimensions, as mentioned in [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28674267/android-app-layout-looks-bad-with-hardcoded-values) questions, is not recommended.